# Reportes en SAP Crystal Reports con consultas SQL

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, sql, sap

En SAP B1 ya trae por defecto un reporte que se llama "Balance Provisional", y te arroja el Saldo inicial, el Débito, el Crédito y Saldo actual.

Es el Siguiente:

[image: Balance Provisional SAP B1]

Bueno aquí la cuestión es generar ese mismo reporte en SAP Crystal Reports desde una consulta SQL, ya tengo una consulta que me arroja perfecto los datos de Débito y Crédito, pero no se como sacar el Saldo inicial ni el saldo actual.

Esta es mi consulta SQL:

```
SELECT 
    T2.[AcctCode], 
    T2.[AcctName], 
    SUM(T1.[Debit]) AS DEBITO, 
    SUM(T1.[Credit]) AS CREDITO
FROM 
    OJDT T0  INNER JOIN JDT1 T1 ON T0.[TransId] = T1.[TransId] 
    INNER JOIN OACT T2 ON T1.[Account] = T2.[AcctCode] 
WHERE 
    T1.[Account] >= '11020000' 
    AND  T1.[Account] <='11020105' 
    AND  T1.[RefDate] >='2017-02-01' 
    AND  T1.[RefDate] <= '2017-02-28' 
GROUP BY 
    T2.[AcctCode], 
    T2.[AcctName]
```

Espero sus respuestas saludos!!!

Comment: bienvenido bro, date una vuelta por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que quede claro la manera adecuada de cómo funciona el presente sitio :D

Comment: Lo are, Gracias!

Comment: de nada bro, luego editas tu pregunta clickeando aqui: http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/60765/edit (está justo debajo de las etiquetas de tu pregunta en caso no lo hayas visto) agregas todos los detalles posible para poder reproducir lo que te sucede y así darte una buena respuesta :D

Comment: Gracias por la orientación, estoy trabajando en eso!!!

Comment: de nada hermano, para eso estamos en la hermandad de SOes :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saldo Inicial es el Saldo anterior a la Fecha desde, es decir

```
SELECT T2.[AcctCode], 
       T2.[AcctName], 
       SUM(T1.[Debit] - T1.[Credit]) AS Saldo
       FROM OJDT T0 INNER JOIN JDT1 T1 
            ON T0.[TransId] = T1.[TransId] 
       INNER JOIN OACT T2 
            ON T1.[Account] = T2.[AcctCode] 
       WHERE T1.[Account] >= '11020000' 
             AND T1.[Account] <='11020105' 
             AND T1.[RefDate] < '2017-02-01' 
       GROUP BY T2.[AcctCode], T2.[AcctName]
```

Esta consulta la puedes incorporar al SELECT principal con un LEFT JOIN

Comment: Mil gracias amigo, me sirvió bastante, solo me podrías ayudar con el LEFT JOIN, por favor!

Answer (score 0):

Ya quedo resuelto les dejo la consulta por si a alguien mas le interesa.
Saludos!!!

```
SELECT 
     T2.[AcctCode], 
     T2.[AcctName], 
     (SELECT 
           SUM(I.Debit - I.Credit)
      FROM 
           JDT1 I
      WHERE 
           T1.[Account] = I.Account 
           AND I.RefDate < '2017-02-01')
     AS SI, 
     SUM(T1.[Debit]) AS DEBITO, 
     SUM(T1.[Credit]) AS CREDITO, 
     (SELECT 
            SUM(F.Debit - F.Credit)
      FROM 
            JDT1 F
      WHERE 
            T1.[Account] = F.Account 
            AND F.RefDate < '2017-03-01')
     AS SALDO
FROM 
     OJDT T0  
     INNER JOIN JDT1 T1 ON T0.[TransId] = T1.[TransId] 
     INNER JOIN OACT T2 ON T1.[Account] = T2.[AcctCode] 
WHERE 
     T1.[Account] >= '11020000' AND 
     T1.[Account] <='11020105' AND 
     T1.[RefDate] >='2017-02-01' AND 
     T1.[RefDate] <= '2017-02-28' 
GROUP BY 
     T2.[AcctCode], T2.[AcctName], T1.[Account]
ORDER BY 
     T2.[AcctCode]
```